# In flutter, how to set dark/light theme as per the value stored in data base?

Tags: flutter, dart

When app launches I want the theme of an app based on value stored in data base. How can I do that? What I need to do in main class?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(

    create:(context) => ThemeProvider(),
    builder:(context,_){
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor:mRed,
      ));
      final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context,listen: true);
      return MaterialApp(

        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        supportedLocales: []
 themeMode: themeProvider.thememode,
        theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
```

This is theme class and in this I have an option to set ThemeMode.system/dark/light but I here I want to ditch the phone settings and wants to update it on the basis of value stored in database. Just wanted to know where to add that part of code so that it listens the value from database:-

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier{

ThemeMode thememode = ThemeMode.system;

  
bool get isDarkMode => thememode == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme(bool isOn){
    thememode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyThemes{
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: dRed,
    primaryColor: dRed,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(),
    textTheme: TextTheme(),


  );

  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: white,
    primaryColor: white,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(),
     textTheme: TextTheme(),

  );
}
```

Comment: You need to store the setting. [Some examples](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence)

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a dart file to notify listeners about theme and put the following code in it:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;

  ThemeNotifier(this._themeData);

  getTheme() => _themeData; // to get current theme of the app

  setTheme(ThemeData themeData) async {
    _themeData = themeData;
    notifyListeners(); // to update the theme of the app
  }
}
```

Add [Shared prefs](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin in your pubspec.yaml file

Now, lets work on the void main. So, lets create a function to get the current theme of the device, if you don't have any value of the current theme/mode in database.
For example, if the user have just installed the app then you don't know the theme choice of the user then it would be great if you provide theme based on the users mobile theme.

```
getSystemTheme()
  {
    var brightness = SchedulerBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;
    bool darkModeOn = brightness == Brightness.dark;
    return darkModeOn;
  }
```

Above function will return boolean value whether dark theme is on or

Now lets fetch the value from the local database and provide theme accordingly.

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values).then((_) {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      var darkModeOn = prefs.getBool('isDarkTheme') ?? getSystemTheme(); //if have value in database then that theme else the system theme will be used
      runApp(
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
          create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(darkModeOn ? MyThemes.darktheme : MyThemes.lightTheme),
          child: MyApp(),
        ),
      );
    });
  });
```

Now the code for MyApp() widget:-

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeNotifier = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
    return Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
      builder: (context, appState, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: themeNotifier.getTheme(),
          home: HomeScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to give your user option to change theme manually then you can create a switch for it and do following updates to change theme dynamically(without restarting the app).:-

```
    class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
    
      @override
      _SettingsState createState() => _SettingsState();
    }
    
    class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
      bool _darkTheme=false;

      void toggleSwitch(bool value, ThemeNotifier themeNotifier) async {
    (value)
        ? themeNotifier.setTheme(AppTheme.darktheme)
        : themeNotifier.setTheme(AppTheme.lighttheme);//here change of theme will take place
        var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setBool('isDarkTheme', value); // and this code will save the boolean value whether darkmode is on or off to the local storage.
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final themeNotifier = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
        _darkTheme = (themeNotifier.getTheme() == MyThemes.darktheme);

        return Scaffold(
            body: Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: Text("Dark Mode",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),)),
                Switch(
                  value: _darkTheme,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _darkTheme = val;
                    });
                    toggleSwitch(val, themeNotifier);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            )
         );
      }
    }
```

P.S.:- You can see my first app in which i used it about an yr ago:-[Attendance Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exordium.attendanceassistant)

Comment: If you didn't got it. Feel free to contact me : )

Comment: Thanks for this a lot but theme part has already done and it can be changed manually by the user choice and it is also getting stored in data base since the beginning  here I just wanted to know how to set theme just listening the  value stored in database and not the phone settings. How can I ditch the phone settings and just want the app to listen the data base.

Comment: In the 3rd section of my code am using shared prefs. to fetch the database and accordingly providing the theme